# More general image recognition than face (e.g. Picasa) for sorting images?

Tags: windows, images, picasa

Picasa and Windows Live Gallery do not recognize faces of cartoon characters. Is there any Windows software that can do more general image recognition?

Answer (score 2):

Yes goto http://www.generalpicturerecognition.com

Its software that given a sample or by using a default sample will go off and recognise groups of pictures. Please goto the web-site for more information. The software has some very advanced methods but at the same time is easy to use.

Very powerful software and there is nothing else out there that seems to do exactly the same thing.  You can give it any picture and it will find similar pictures.

If you cannot find a picture your looking for on your computer then this is the software that's been designed to solve the problem.

Now also comes with web-crawler Internet search and motion detection.  Anyway hope this is helpful.